# When using Mahapps.Metro, last header of a GridView shows double vertical line

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

[image: GridViewColumnHeader]

I have a WPF project which uses Mahapps.Metro theming.
When a theme is applied - `GridView`'s last `ColumnHeader` shows two vertical lines.
Is it possible to show only one vertical line instead?
Checked in code-behind, `GridView` has 4 columns indeed.
Tried changing these styles:
`MahApps.Styles.GridViewColumnHeader`
`MahApps.Styles.Thumb.GridViewColumnHeaderGripper`.
But nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
Change style: "MahApps.Styles.GridViewColumnHeader",
Element: "Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"".
Change its Margin from "0 0 -9 0" to "0 0 0 0"